# What font is used in this Stack Overflow Careers ad?

Tags: support, jobs, advertising, fonts

I know Stack Overflow logo is using FF DIN.

Now, what font is the word "Work on work you love. From home." in the below Careers ad?

[image: ad image]

Comment: Could be [Consolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas)

Comment: @fredley Nah, the Consolas lowercase `l` is different, but otherwise close. It looks similar to [Linefeed](http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/typodermic/linefeed) too, but the `m` and `e` seem like they're a bit off

Comment: Hmm, my best guess is actually [Arial Monospaced](http://www.linotype.com/164742/arial-monospaced-regular-product.html) with some presentation tweaks, although the bias in spacing of the lowercase `m` might opposite at the font size in the ad. In any case, hopefully the ad designer comes along and gives us a definitive answer

Answer (score 5):

Comparing the screenshot from the Question
with the Font suggested by @TimStone

[image]

It has to be [Arial Monospaced](http://www.linotype.com/164742/arial-monospaced-regular-product.html).

In the future, you can use [WhatFont extension on Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en) to identify fonts used on any site as long as it is in text format.